# How I can bind the div id for dynamically for binding c3 js chart into the div in angular2

Tags: angular, c3.js

How I can bind the div id for dynamically for binding c3 js chart into the div.
I have used attr.id and [id] etc but none of its not working. please someone can help me out of this.

```
@Component({
selector: 'chart-component',
template: <h1>{{chartId}}</h1>
 <div [id] = {{chartId}} class="c3"> </div>

})


export class ChartComponent implements OnInit
{

  constructor(){ }

  @Input('chartType') chartType:string;
  @Input('chartId') chartId:Object;
  @Input('chartData') chartData:any[];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartId = Object("chart1");
    let chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#'+this.chartId,   
        data: {
            json:this.chartData,
            type: this.chartType,
        },
        legend: {
              show: true
        }
  });

}
}
```

from html calling the component below mentioned.

```
<chart-component chartType="bar" chartId="chart1" [chartData]="chartData">
```

I have tried to use object as div id but still its not working.

Thanks,

Arun s

Comment: Can you add your `chartData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `[]` and `{{}}` together. Either the one

```
[id]="chartId"
```

or the other

```
id="{{chartId}}"
```

And you need to use `ngAfterViewInit` hook instead of `ngOnInit` because your `id` binding has not applied yet.

Here's **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NgcBKAhqNica64kxmCX4?p=preview)**

Comment: its working fine..thank you so much for the help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

The is the purpose of `@Hostbinding`. I would throw an attribute directive on it and within the directive use something like:

```
@HostBinding('attr.id') id = '#'+this.chartId;
```

I'm not certain of the logic you'll need, but something along these lines.